# std::vector not retaining pushed back objects instantiated in the implementation

Tags: c++, vector, scope, implementation

I have a vector and an object declared in plane.h:

```
extern Plane Default;
extern std::vector<Plane *>universe;
```

They are defined in plane.cpp:

```
Plane Default("Default");
std::vector<Plane *>universe;
```

Plane constructor:

```
Plane::Plane(const std::string &label) {
    /* check universe to ensure uniqueness */
    std::cout << this << std:endl; //DEBUG CHECK to see what I push_back

    universe.push_back(this); //ACTION to keep track of the planes

    std::cout << universe.back() << std::endl; //DEBUG CHECK to ensure that it was stored correctly
}
```

The output confirms that the plane is indeed stored in the vector.

In main:

```
if(universe.empty()) cout << "EMPTY UNIVERSE" << endl;
```

shows that the vector has not retained the value. I expected the Default (as defined in plane.cpp) to be stored in the universe.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a927299d2d04068b)

However, universe retains the values when I instantiate planes from main

I guess it has to do with local copies, scope and passing by value, but I can't figure out a way to instantiate the default plane INSIDE the implementation so that its address is preserved in the vector.

I also tried declaring the vector off the heap, like so:

```
extern std::vector<Plane *> *universe;
```

and defined like so:

```
std::vector<Plane *> *universe = new std::vector<Plane *>;
```

It just crashed the program.
I use a MinGW32 4.9 on a 64-bit Vista machine in Code:Blocks 16.01 and -std=C++11

Comment: Can you boil this all down into an [mcve]?

Comment: global initialization order fiasco...

Comment: My guess is you passed the `universe` by value, put the `Plane` into the copy, destroyed the copy and then checked the original if it contains the `Plane`, which it does not. But without seeing the code this is just speculation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You hit the global initialization order fiasco:

```
Plane Default("Default");
std::vector<Plane *>universe;
```

`Default` has a dependency on `universe`, but when construct `Default`, `universe` has not been yet constructed.

That is why you should avoid global in general.

A work-around in your case would be to change the order assuming there are in same translation unit:

```
std::vector<Plane *>universe;
Plane Default("Default");
```

Comment: I just confirmed that this indeed fixes the problem: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba1d03cb9f19b380.

Comment: Nitpick: TTBOMK the static initialization order fiasco occurs when you have static variables in *different* source files -- since whether or not the program works correctly depends on which order the linker processes them, IOW, it is (generally) not even under the programmer's control!  Here, while it's certainly crappy that the program compiles without warnings and gives the wrong behaviour, the programmer can at least guarantee correct program behaviour by getting the order of definitions right.

Comment: This was indeed the issue. Your solution worked like a charm! Many thanks for the useful response.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36134728/434551) should resolve the problem you are having. I am going to offer some guidelines to prevent issues like these.

In general, it is better to avoid global data that are accessible using an `extern` declared variable. It is better to provide access to global data using a function interface.

You can change

```
extern std::vector<Plane *>universe;
```

to

```
extern std::vector<Plane *>& getUniverse();
```

and implement it as:

```
extern std::vector<Plane *>& getUniverse()
{
   static std::vector<Plane *>universe;
   return universe;
}
```

With that in place, you can change the constructor of `Plane` to:

```
 Plane::Plane(const std::string &label) {
    getUniverse().push_back(this);
}
```

This will remove the problems associated with order of initialization of global data.

You can also change

```
extern Plane Default;
```

to

```
extern Plane& getDefaultPlane();
```

and implement it as

```
extern Plane& getDefaultPlane()
{
   static Plane Default("Default");
   return Default;
}
```

If a default `Plane` must be constructed at initialization time, you can use something along the lines of:

```
// Use a helper struct in an anonymous namespace to initialize
// whatever needs to be initialized.
namespace
{
    struct Initializer
    {
       Initializer();
    };
}

// Make sure that Initializer::Initializer() gets called
// at initialization time.
static Initializer initer;

Initializer::Initializer()
{
   // Trigger construction of the default Plane
   getDefaultPlane();
}
```

Comment: Good advice, but the OP's problem doesn't involve multiple translation units, so the part about extern visibility doesn't seem to be relevant here.  Also I haven't seen the approach in your last section ("If a default `Plane`...) before, and am wondering what it achieves, either in general, or in the single-translation-unit case.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, it provides you a technique to force initialization of objects at start up time with a greater degree of control on the order of initialization than could be accomplished using global data.

Comment: How interesting! I am quite new to C++ (and programming in general). I love the layer of abstraction that your solution adds. I just implemented your way.

Comment: @EhsanAmini, glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble with the scope of your pointers, perhaps using shared_ptr would suffice? I do not know your overall design, however, if you are worried about the persistence of pointers that may be deleted or moved and still need the data; a smart pointer may be the answer. If there is an issue of cycles anywhere use weak_ptr to break it.

Good luck!

Comment: This sounds like an extended comment, not an answer.

Comment: Yeah, don't have enough rep for comment post apparently... so seemed appropriate to add any advice as an answer.

Comment: Actually, the problem was, as correctly pointed out by @Jarod42 and R Sahu, the order of initialization. Changing the order solved the issue, and adding an initializer further improved it. But as noted before, I'm quite new to programming. I am going to look into shared_ptr and smart pointers. Thanks for the cue.